# UNIX: unrecognized EOF rule pattern in lex

Tags: parsing, unix, lex

Using `flex` offers you the opportunity to handle an end of file with the pattern [`<<EOF>>`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/EOF.html).

Is there any similar solution with `lex(1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; what you describe is a `flex` extension.